# Browsable folders on Stack Overflow Blog, may be not good for security?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blog, security

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/plugins/podpress/
>
> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-includes/
>
> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-admin/includes/

May be putting `Options -Indexes` in `.htaccess` file would solve that?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/plugins/podpress/screenshot-2.jpgb

Comment: I think there is typo in your link - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/plugins/podpress/screenshot-2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report - this has been tweaked.